# Regex parsing using Kimono Labs

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I am attempting to use software supplied by Kimonolabs to get a list of articles and their links from a web site. The problem I am having is that a string I have scraped from the web site has a date along with some text that I am unable to separate from the date.

Kimono uses this syntax for a regex:

> /^()(.*?)()$/

first bracket => to the left of the required content

second bracket => this is what should get extracted

third bracket => to the right of the required content

Specifically the website I am trying to scrape is:
http://www.yashinquesada.com/futbol-nacional

Here is an example of the line I am trying to parse (I only want the date):

```
<p class="nspInfo  nspInfo1 tleft fnone">Enero 08, 2016 <a href="/futbol-nacional/28-la-primera" >La Primera</a></p>
```

My attempts to parse this line returned no results, I have tried reading through regex reference materials but they are pretty complicated for me.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Hi! If my answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted. If it did not help you, you should leave a comment. In any case, not reacting in any way is considered rude.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expressions Kimono expects need to have three groups (a group is a pair of parentheses). That means you always need to keep this structure:

```
/^()(.*?)()$/
```

This is Kimono's default, where the first group is empty, the second contains all the text (`.` matches any character, `*?` basically means *"any number of times"*), and the third is empty again.

You can adapt that arrangement to cut off unwanted text at the beginning and at the end - the value that ends up in your data will always be whatever the middle group matches.

I suspect the values you currently get currently are looking like this:

```
Enero 07, 2016 La Primera
```

so what you actually want to do is cut off text at the end.

Let's make the second and third groups more specific. We know the date always contains the year, which is four digits (`\d\d\d\d` or `\d{4}`) - and actually the match should end there. That's fairly easy:

```
/^()(.*?\d{4})(.*)$/
```

So, in English:

- first group stays empty, no cut-off at the beginning
- second group matches any character, but stops after matching four digits
- third group matches the remainder of the value; Kimono will throw away that substring

Play around with the expression over at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/rM3tX0/1